# How to request and get a webpage using http request in jsp

Tags: jsp

How do I get an xml page (I mean an REST API from an web service), parse it and display it in my website, in jsp?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a library to retrieve the content via HTTP ([HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/), for example) and something to parse the response (SAX).

Avoid using scriptlets for doing this, encapsulate your logic in classes and try creating [custom tags](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaiy.html), or better yet, try using something like [Spring's MVC](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/07/22/spring-mvc-3-showcase/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the complete answer but here is how to get a web page at least. I'm trying to do something similar so will come back when I have more.

```
<%@page import="java.net.*" %>
<%@page import="java.io.*" %>

<%
   URL dest = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/");
   URLConnection yc = dest.openConnection();
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                           new InputStreamReader(
                           yc.getInputStream()));
   String inputLine;

   while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
       System.out.println(inputLine);
   in.close();
%>
```