# java/javascript read online XML file

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I would like to get the data from the online xml file e.g. http://data.one.gov.hk/others/td/speedmap.xml.
It works when I call the javascript from HTML locally (without servlet).
However, it does not work when I call it through jsp and java servlet. 
Is there another method such that I can get the data from the online xml file?

contentXML.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>CONTENT_XML</p>

        <%@ include file="source_file/js_workable.js" %>
        <%@ include file="source_file/data_retrieve.js" %>

    </body>
</html>
```

data_retrieve.js

```
<script  LANGUAGE="JavaScript">


         if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
           xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
         }
         else { // code for IE6, IE5
           xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }

         document.write(xmlhttp.status);
         document.write(xmlhttp.readyState);
         document.write(xmlhttp.statusText);

         xmlhttp.open("GET","http://data.one.gov.hk/others/td/speedmap.xml",false);
         xmlhttp.send(); 


         xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

         document.write("<table border='1'>");
         var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("jtis_speedmap");
         for (i=0;i<x.length;i++){ 
           document.write("<tr><td>");
           document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("LINK_ID")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
           document.write("</td><td>");
           document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ROAD_TYPE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
           document.write("</td></tr>");
         }
         document.write("</table>");

</script>
```

html file:

```
<html>
 <body>

<script>
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","http://data.one.gov.hk/others/td/speedmap.xml",false);
 xmlhttp.send();
 xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table border='1'>");
 var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("jtis_speedmap");
 for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
   { 
  document.write("<tr><td>");
   document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("LINK_ID")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
   document.write("</td><td>");
   document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ROAD_TYPE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
   document.write("</td></tr>");
   }
 document.write("</table>");
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where does it fail? Reading the XML or parsing it? Add logs to your browser console to see the cause better.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Is there an exception from `js_workable.js` maybe? Would you mind posting only the served HTML page, not the jsp code? Btw, `LANGUAGE="JavaScript"` is deprecated.

Comment: I am not sure the cause right now. I will check this. BTW thank you for yours suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is cross domain ajax request, so it was blocked by Access-Control-Allow-Origin rules.

solution you may use jsp / servlet made a HTTP request to retrive the XML content first, and then your ajax request locally to go on your javascript.

Comment: Thank you! Would you give me some related websites for me so that I can learn more about it? For example, jsp / servlet made a HTTP request to retrive the XML content.

Comment: @user1976340, Hi, I dont know much on JSP. but i think it may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8369324/782072