# Getting Error When sending data from JSP to Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am using Dynamic Web Project. 
This is my JSP Code. I am trying to send Hello to servlet

```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
  pageEncoding="ISO-   
  8859-1"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <jsp:include page="/servlet/ServletCode" flush="true" >
   <jsp:param name="username" value="Hello" />
   </jsp:include>
   </body>
   </html>
```

This is my Servlet File.

```
package pack.exp;

public class ServletCode extends HttpServlet 
{
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws ServletException, IOException
{
    String output= request.getParameter("username");
    System.out.println(output);
     PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
     pw.println("Hello " + output);
}
}
```

In my JSP File I am getting this compile time error on this line.

Fragment "/servlet/ServletCode" was not found at expected path /JSpServletCode/WebContent/servlet/ServletCode

Please Help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You have to map your servlet in the web.xml, and the servlet-url you have to provide in the page. Something like below whould work.

```
<jsp:include page="/ServletCode" flush="true" > 

 <servlet>
         <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
         <servlet-path>pack.exp.ServletCode</servlet-path>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/ServletCode</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**UPDATE**

This is working for me

**SERVLET**

```
 @WebServlet("/ServletCode")
  public class ServletCode extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ServletCode() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            String output= request.getParameter("username");
            System.out.println(output);
             PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
             pw.println("Hello " + output);
        }
}
```

**JSP**

```
<body>
    <jsp:include page="/ServletCode" flush="true">
        <jsp:param name="username" value="Hello" />
    </jsp:include>
</body>
```

Comment: @ A Paul
Thanx for  your reply buddy. I made changes in the web.xml.
But Now as a Output I am getting Hello null. But output should be hello hello

Comment: Ok. That means the param is not going to your servlet. Code looks fine to me. Let me check.

Comment: can you check if System.out.println(output); is printing value or null

Comment: @  A Paul
It is printing null.

Comment: Not sure what is the problem. But it is working for me. Just created a test project and checked. It is coming as "Hello Hello" for me

Comment: @ A Paul  when i am running the project on apache tomcat server I am getting this error. "HTTP Status 404 - /JSpServletCode/"
and this is the url which is displaying this error.   http://localhost:8080/JSpServletCode/.  I think the url must be http://localhost:8080/JSpServletCode/ServletCode. But I dont know why it is not showing the servlet class name in the url while running

Comment: you have to run your jsp in tomcat. I am also using Tomcat. if your jsp name is test.jsp and if you have placed it under the WebContent folder of you project. Then you can do http://localhost:8080/JSpServletCode/test.jsp

Comment: @ A Paul
Hey can you tell me how to call a servlet which is in another project from a JSP page which is in other project.

Comment: the 2 projects are they running in same tomcat with different ports. How they are running.

Comment: the JSP one is running on tomcat and the other project will have a servlet which will receive the data from JSP and then I will run the servlet as a web application.

Comment: @ A Paul Can you help me out with the previous comment

Comment: Can you please tell me what you are referring to. What is your issue please?

Comment: @ A Paul  My issue is that I want to pass some data to the servlet which is in a web application project from a jsp which is in a dynamic application project. I am unable to find out what I have to do to make this happen. Please help me out.

Comment: Can you please tell me what are you actually trying to achieve by doing this. I think there is a better way to do that or may be I am wrong.

Comment: @  A Paul
My main aim is to deploy the data from the servlet web application to the google app engine datastore. And that data is comin to the servlet from the jsp .

Comment: Check the url. You can just call the servlet in the url of the example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178807/how-to-request-and-get-a-webpage-using-http-request-in-jsp

Comment: @ A Paul I followed that link. i am using this url "http://localhost:8080/ServletToCloud/JSPToServletToCloudServlet"
where ServletToCloud is the name of the web application and JSPToServletToCloudServlet is the name of the servlet. Is this the right way to give the url?

Comment: @ A Paul I added it. I am 1st running the Jsp file on tomcat server. The server is starting properly then I am running the Servlet application as web application and after getting the confirmation on console that the Dev App Server is running I am checking it on (http ://localhost:8888/jsptoservlettocloud); and I am getting this error "HTTP ERROR 500 Problem accessing /jsptoservlettocloud. Reason: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR" – user3273473 5 mins ago

Comment: its a coding error that you are getting. Please debug your application check what request is going.

Comment: @ A Paul I am getting exception in this line ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(request.getInputStream()); in the servlet

Answer (score 0):

this is model servlet page:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>registerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.RegisterServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>registerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/register</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And you must change the form like this format:

```
<form action="register" method="post">
```

this is do Post method:

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
 PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
     pw.println("Hello " + output);
System.out.println(output); 
       // ...
    }
```

Comment: now I am getting this  error "HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL"

Comment: try doGet instead of doPost method same signature